# Meaning of that Gnu/Linux sentence

Tags: debian, command-line

What is Gnu/Linux actually doing when I run these commands?

```
cd; ls /Bin/g* &> /dev/null; echo $?
```

The final output is 0.

Comment: do you understand any parts of it? What context did this come from? What's your interpretation, given what you've learned from the `man` pages on the commands?

Comment: Also, it'd be unusual for a GNU/Linux system to have a `/Bin` directory; did a text editor "helpfully" capitalize that for you along the way, or was it intentional?

Comment: We can help with homework, but you need to put in some effort. We won't do it for you, you need to learn.

Comment: Tip: The `cd` is useless, it dose nothing that is observable yet. Look in `man bash` (if you are using bash), search for `$?` and for `&>`. E.g. to search for `$?` type `man bash | less -i '+/$?'`, then type `/` enter, to find the next one, and `q` to quit.

Comment: wrong , the cd isnt useless that is if you for some reason wants to return to your home-dir.  Though 'cd .'  is somewhat useless.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund In the context of this exercise, it's useless, unless `ls` is called without an argument (pattern does not match and `nullglob` is set)  and the directory that `cd` brings you to has a different access rights compared to the original working directory for the current user, affecting the exit status of `ls` running with no arguments.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund there is a (strange and very occasional) use for `cd .`. Consider `mkdir -p a/b/c; cd a/b/c; touch a/b/c/x`. Now in another shell `mv a/b/c .; mkdir a/b/c; touch a/b/c/y`. Back in shell 1 `ls` gives `x`. If you `cd .; ls` you get `y`.

Answer (score 2):

If the intent is to determine whether there are names starting wih the letter `g` in the directory `/Bin`, then a better way of doing that would
be, in the `bash` shell,

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- /Bin/g*
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
    printf 'There are %d names starting with "g" in /Bin\n' "$#"
    echo 'These are those names:'
    printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
else
    echo 'No names in /Bin start with "g"'
fi
```

---

Assuming that you are on a system which is running `bash`...

The set of commands output `0` if there are names matching the pattern `/Bin/g*`, and will output a non-zero value (possibly `2`, maybe `1`, but at least non-zero) if there are no names matching that pattern, or if certain directory permissions do not allow `ls` to produce a listing.

The `cd` at the start is fairly uninteresting and potentially not needed (the circumstances under which removing this command would make a difference is quite contrived). It changes your current directory to be whatever the value `$HOME` is, or to your home directory as defined by `/etc/passwd` (or the equivalent database) if `HOME` is unset.

Before the `ls` command is executed, the shell will expand the `/Bin/g*` pattern to a list of matching names.  If you have access to read the directory listing of `/Bin` and if there are names in the `/Bin` directory starting with the letter `g`, then a list of these names will be replacing the pattern as the arguments to `ls`.  If there are no matches, or if you don't have the correct access rights to `/Bin`, then the pattern will be retained as is.

When `ls` is executed, it takes the list of arguments given to it by the shell's expansion of `/Bin/g*` and tries to list these names.  Given that the names exists, and given that you have access to list any *subdirectory* of `/Bin` that starts with the letter `g`, the `ls` command will finally terminate successfully and return an exit status of `0`.  If the names do *not* exist, or if one of the names refer to a subdirectory that you don't have access to list the contents of, it will fail and return a non-zero exit status (GNU `ls` returns `2` in these cases).

The `&>/dev/null` is a redirection that, in the `bash` shell, would redirect both the standard output stream and the standard error stream to `/dev/null`.  When `ls` runs, this means that all output and all errors from that command will be discarded (`/dev/null` is a special device file that, when written to, discards all data). The `&>` redirection operator is not standard and is better written as `>/dev/null 2>&1`, i.e. "redirect standard output to `/dev/null`, and then redirect standard error to the same place that standard output goes to". This step is technically happening even before the shell expands the `/Bin/g*` globbing pattern.

The final `echo $?` outputs the most recent exit status.  This will be the exit status of `ls` (or possibly the error code resulting from failing to expand the pattern `/Bin/g*`, or possibly the error code resulting from not being able to run `ls` at all if it's not found in `$PATH`, see below).

Two shell options affect this:

1. If the `nullglob` option is set in the current shell session, then the pattern `/Bin/g*` would be *removed completely* instead of being retained.  This means that `ls` would be run without arguments, and it would list the contents of the *current* directory (which is likely your home directory, after that `cd`). This would be successful if you have access to read the current directory.  If you do not have access to read the directory contents, `ls` will return a non-zero exit status (GNU `ls` will return `1` in this case).
2. If the `failglob` shell option is set and no names matches the pattern `/Bin/*`, then the *shell* would complain with `no match: /Bin/g*` and you'd get a non-zero exit status (probably `1`; and `ls` would not even run at all).

   Since it is the shell producing the error message, and since the standard error stream of the shell is *not* sent to `/dev/null` (remember, it's only the output streams of `ls` that are redirected, and `ls` isn't even run in this scenario) this error message would be printed in your terminal before the final `echo $?` prints `1`.

One shell variable affects this:

- The `IFS` variable comes into effect when the shell expands an unquoted value. This is what you do in the very last step (`echo $?`).  When the shell expands `$?` to be able to call `echo` with the correct value, it first splits the value into words using the characters in `$IFS` as delimiters to split on.  By default, `$IFS` is a space, a tab character, and a newline character.

  If `IFS` was to be set to the string `012` (these being the possible values of `$?` if using `bash` and GNU `ls`), then the shell would split the `$?` value (the exit status of `ls`) into an empty string (since the value would just be taken as a delimiter to split on), and `echo` would be called without an argument, producing a lone newline as output.

  To avoid this unfortunate scenario, you would use `echo "$?"` instead (note the double quoting of `$?`).

Not covered:

- `PATH` and what happens and does not happen if `ls` can't be found in `$PATH`, and why this would not affect `cd` and `echo`.
- All the things related to actually executing a command, `fork` + `exec` etc.
- Alias expansions or shell functions overriding any of the tools `cd`, `ls` or `echo`.
- What happens in a non-`bash` shell and why?
- The effect of `set -f`.